# Google Maps Embed API Not Displaying

Tags: api, google-maps, embed

I have followed the step-by-step on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start and uploaded files to server. I continue to get error displayed on page: "The Google Maps API server rejected your request. This API project is not authorized to use this API." The website is https://www.careforce.ca

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Do what the message says: "The Google Maps API server rejected your request. This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 192.107.155.7, with referrer: https://www.careforce.ca/".

Authorize the key (key=AIzaSyAqCUj4KiU7VyBtMSaQibCMsaweePqYpKU) for the referrer or IP Address.

You have a [restriction on it](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/get-api-key#key-restrictions)

[See the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/get-api-key)

Comment: Thank you. I did have an HTTP restriction on the API key and have now removed it. It still can't be verified, but I will wait the few minutes it says.